# Get value from subquery in CodeIgniter beetween month and year

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanna get data from this table
[image]

11-2015  until 03-2016

how to get that table using active record in codeigniter

Comment: Why seperate your month and year on your table?

Comment: Why not use `timestamp`, or `date` column type, then you can make interesting queries based on SQL supported TIME/DATE support

Answer (score 2):

You can combine 2 field into single string, then parse it to date like this

```
STR_TO_DATE('01/'+pengadaan_bulan+'/'+pengadaan_tahun, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

So you can query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('01/'+pengadaan_bulan+'/'+pengadaan_tahun, '%d/%m/%Y') 
BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```